# Angular submission by Javascript event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I am creating my first web app using Angular and Express. The app contains a canvas, in which I am keeping a list of the points being drawn on it. Currently, there is an empty textbox next to the canvas, and when the user presses 'Enter' in the textbox, then my list of points will be returned via ng-submit, i.e. (shown using Jade)

```
body(ng-controller="Controller", onload="init()")
   canvas#can(width='2000',height='800',style='not important')
   img#canvasimg(style='not important')

   form(ng-submit="submit('" + target + "')")
      input(ng-model="under")
   li(ng-repeat="value in results track by $index") {{value}}
```

For the above code, 'results' refers to the list of points, and 'under' is the same list of points being returned (i.e. referenced by req.body.under from a separate js file...not sure how to eliminate the redundancy yet).

My main problem is that I don't want the user to press a button or manually specify when ng-submit is run. Instead, I want list of points returned based on an event listener defined in Javascript, i.e.

```
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
   //return list of points here
}, false);
```

Since ng-submit is part of a form, the triggered event for when the list of points is returned occurs when the form is submitted. So essentially, how can I instead rely on the event listener for 'mouseup' that I defined in JS?

Note: I have looked at ngMouseUp, but haven't been able to return or 'submit' my list of points in a similar way that ng-submit did. It also seems redundant to have two different event listeners monitor the same event.

**Edit:**
One hacky solution I just tried was to systematically click a Submit button from the JS event listener via

```
document.getElementById("button-id").click();
```

This seems to work but I'm not very proud of it. Am still very interested in suggestions for a cleaner solution.